# JPA Mapping embedded fields with createNativeQuery

Tags: jpa, mapping

I have an entity with has a field which represents composite primary key annotated with embeddeid and another field which is annotated with embedded annotation. 
Both of these fields are not directly mapped with the the columns returned by the query passed to createNativeQuery method.
The getResultList returns me the list of entities, but the two fields which I mentioned are null in all the entities.

```
public interface Key{
 public int hashCode()
}

@Embeddable
public class CompositePK impements Key{
   private int empid;
   private Date startdate;
   private Date enddate;
}

@Embeddable
public class PartitionKey implements Key{
   private String empname;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
 @EmbeddedId
 private CompositePK id;

 @Embedded
 private PartitionKey name;

 @Column(name="empid")
 private int empid;

 @Column(name="empname")
 private String empname;

 @Column(name="startdate")
  private Date startdate;

 @Column(name="enddate")
  private Date enddate;     
}

public class Loader{
 private static EntityManager em;
 public static void main(String [] args){
 //code to instantiate em goes here
 //...
 //....
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select empid,empname,startdate,enddate from employees", Employee.class );
 List entities = query.getResultList();
 //print the list
 System.out.println(entities);
 }
}
```

The outcome of this is that the entities are populated but their fieldsid and name which are emdedded fields are null. Can anyone please suggest how to populate these two fields?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged "embedded"? Probably not apropriate here.

Comment: I am new to JPA. So I'm not sure whether I'm right but I want to entity to hold the object and not the reference to another object.

Comment: the tag "embedded" is for embedded computing - microcontrollers and such